# Javascript equivalent for php "use"

Tags: javascript

is there a way to access an external variable inside a javascript function ?
In other words, is there an equivalent of "use" in php

```
function ($quantity) use ($tax, &$total) { .. };
```

The code i'm struggling with is the following :

```
function removePosition(menu) {
    msgManager.confirm('Delete ?').then(() => {
        menu.closest('.clockingPositionContainer').remove();
    });
}
```

Comment: does this help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/500459/11260991

Comment: In JavaScript the `use` keyword is implicitly always there, as all global variables are available in each inner scope of the same module.

Comment: What is the issue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scope is the region of the codebase over which an identifier is valid.

The four scopes are:

- Global - visible by everything
- Function - visible within a function (and its sub-functions and blocks)
- Block - visible within a block (and its sub-blocks)
- Module - visible within a module

[Read More Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/500459/11260991)